# how @JsonKey(toJson: toJSON_SalesInvoiceDetail,) function works in flutter Jsonserializable

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization, key

I am new to this serialization, I am facing a hard time understanding the difference between these two functionalities while serialization in dart/flutter `@JsonKey(name: invoice)`  **&&**  `@JsonKey(toJson: toJSON_SalesInvoiceDetail)`

I see my friend wrote this below function outside the class for the above json key `@JsonKey(toJson: toJSON_SalesInvoiceDetail)` as I see this maps another class so it's kind of embedding one class into another but I do not know how this serialization is happening under the hood, could anyone guide me about this pls, Your help will be appreciated a lot, thanks in advance

[image]

[image: This class we have and one function mentioned above]

Answer (score 4):

The param `toJson` changes the `value` of JSON(**only the method toJson**), and the param `name` changes the `key` (**both of the methods toJson and fromJson**).

For example, I made a class like the following.

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Any {
  const Any(this.param);
  factory Any.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AnyFromJson(json);

  @JsonKey(name: 'json_key_of_param', toJson: paramToJson)
  final int param;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AnyToJson(this);
}

String paramToJson(int paramValue) {
  return 'param value is $paramValue';
}
```

And if we use this like

```dart
print(const Any(100).toJson());
```

then printed the following.

```dart
{json_key_of_param: param value is 100}
```

In this case, I didn't specify the param `fromJson`, so we should use the method fromJson like the following.

```
Any.fromJson(<String, dynamic>{'json_key_of_param': 100});
```

Comment: really sorry I did not get it, we already have two functions, fromJson, and ToJson then why JsonKey needs a toJson Function pls guide thanks

Comment: For example, consider you want to use some param as double in the Flutter application, but API uses the param as String.

 In this case, the argument toJson(and fromJson) is useful. Of cause, you can create another class, but the arguments are a more simple solution in that case.

Comment: I found a more appropriate example.
It's worthwhile If you always want to use some int value like `10k`  but API responses `10000`.

And if you use the value as `String` because you want to use it in Text Input, your code is more straightforward when using this.